# Is it better to loop through a 2D array of n pairings of values or have n if statements? - Java

Tags: arrays, performance, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I need to assess objects adjacent to my current object. There may be one above, below, left and right of my current position. If my current position is `(x, y)`, then my adjacent objects are at positions: `(x-1, y)`, `(x+1, y)`, `(x, y-1)`, `(x, y+1)`.

Is it better to calculate these 4 positions and then store them in a 2D array, traversing them with a `for... in` loop:

```
int[][] adjacentObjects = {
          {x-1, y},
          {x+1, y},
          {x, y-1},
          {x, y+1} };

for (int[] adjacent : adjacentObjects) { ...
  if (adjacent[0] == ...) // x coordinate
  if (adjacent[1] == ...) // y coordinate
```

Or am I better off just having 4 near-identical `if` statements? Each would be 4 lines, where the `x` and `y` coordinates are the only difference.

My current mindset is that the `for... in` loop is cleaner, though not as readable, but I don't really know which is 'better.'

I've also thought about using another method where I'd pass the values of `x` and `y` but I also need access to another two 2D arrays in the current method, and it seems wasteful to send those as parameters to the new method as well.

I'm using Java, but I don't feel this is specific to any one language. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what are you checking in the if and what are you doing in the if if condition fulfilled

Comment: Continuing to the next adjacent pixel. Technically I may be adding them to the queue but I am assessing all 4.

Comment: strictly speaking I would hint that recomputing the offsets for each pixel is better since by using an intermediary object of pixel you still have to iterate over its properties. But 1. This ought to be negligible. 2. It feels like an XY problem and likely you may improve your floodfill algorithm by othermeans. You should provide your code instead

Comment: Unfortunately due to the nature of the assessment I can't really share code (pretty counterintuitive when I'm asking for help here, I know haha). You have given me something to think about, though.